# Getting a list of questions from Code Golf where answers could be eligible for bounty from Jo King using SEDE

Tags: sql, dataexplorer

So on Code Golf.SE, there is a meta post that allows users to post unofficial bounties where a certain feat must be accomplished before a bounty can be awarded.

[@JoKing has a deadlineless bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17337/120105) where 200 reputation will be awarded if these requirements are met:

- The answer is a valid answer
- The answer is posted to an unanswered non-[tips], non-[koth], non-[cops-and-robbers] question
- The question has a score of ≥15.

I, of course, wanted to know what questions would qualify as of right now, and went straight to SEDE to see if I could cook up a program that would allow me to see which questions would be eligible. Right now, [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/1825362/2219054/code-golf-questions-that-are-eligible-for-200-rep-bounty-by-jo-king) is what I have:

```
SELECT p.Id AS [Post Link], u.DisplayName, p.Score, p.ViewCount, p.Tags
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON p.Id = pt.PostId
INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.Id = pt.TagId
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
AND NOT (p.Tags LIKE '%tips%' OR p.Tags LIKE '%king-of-the-hill%' OR p.Tags LIKE '%cops-and-robbers%')
AND p.Score >= 15
AND p.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL
ORDER BY p.Score DESC
```

however I am running into the problem now that yet again, it is returning not only all of the questions, but all of the answers that are posted on questions that don't have the 3 tags I have managed to finally nullify.

For anyone wondering,

```
AND NOT (t.TagName = ##tagName:string?tips## OR t.TagName = ##tagName:string?king-of-the-hill## OR t.TagName = ##tagName:string?cops-and-robbers##)
```

does not work, as it also returns questions/answers with those tags.

So my question is: Why is it returning both questions and answers, and how do I make it so it only returns the questions?

Comment: Presumably you could use PostTypeId to filter for just questions?

Comment: @NickW But that's why I have `WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1`? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. However, why do you think it is returning answers as well as questions? If you mean why is it returning duplicates then that’s because there’s a 1:M relationship between at least 2 of the tables you’re joining. Out of interest, why are you joining to two tables that you don’t reference in your select/where/order clauses?

Comment: @NickW "Why are you joining to two tables that you don't reference in your select/where/order clauses" I was actually referencing previous queries of mine such as [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1822069/list-of-questions-on-p-se-with-score-0score10-and-with-two-tags-finally-works) one to get code. (I couldn't exactly remember off the top of my head the exact code that I needed to be able to nullify the three tags, as that was a previous problem of mine.)

Comment: @NickW NVM, I figured out the problem and am writing an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.

Turns out that the two `INNER JOIN`s aren't even needed.

I was focusing so much on the code that nullified the tags that it wasn't until @NickW mentioned that there was a 1:M relationship between at least two of the tables I was joining (and around 15 minutes after posting my reply to that comment) that I actually decided to see what would happen if I removed the `INNER JOIN`s.

The final code:

```
SELECT p.Id AS [Post Link], u.DisplayName, p.Score, p.Viewcount, p.Tags
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
AND NOT (p.Tags LIKE '%tips%'
OR p.Tags LIKE '%king-of-the-hill%'
OR p.Tags LIKE '%cops-and-robbers%')
AND p.Score >= 15
AND p.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL
ORDER BY p.Score DESC
```

<sup>[<kbd>Query</kbd>](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/1825362/2219081/code-golf-questions-that-are-eligible-for-200-rep-bounty-by-jo-king)</sup>

I am aware that @JoKing might have more specific restrictions that greatly lower the amount of eligible questions, however, the way it is put, it seems that there are a total of 3644 questions that are eligible for bountied answers.